# Как запустить отладку по исходному коду а не дизассемблеру в Qt Creator на linux?

Tags: c++, отладка, qtcreator, gcc, gdb

Я использую Ubuntu 18.04 и Qt Creator 5.
Всегда при отладке, когда пытаюсь пошагово выполнять программу- отлаживает только в дизассемблере. Пробовал переключать окна на исходный код, всё-равно обратно перекидывает на дизассемблер. Пробовал в файле .pro указать: `BUILD_FLAG=debug` - не помогло.
Вот как выглядит отладка приложения: [image: отладка]

Как сделать так, чтобы при пошаговом выполнении отображался именно мой исходный код?

Answer (score 0):

Добавте в флаги компилятора для сборки флаг `-g`. Это заставит компилятор скомпилировать (и слинковать) код с отладочной информацией

Comment: А расскажите подробно, куда именно это указать?

Comment: @НОЧНЫЕБЕСЕДЫ это флаг компилятора, так что это нужно указать компилятору